# My Arbitrum Alchemy node is randomly returning -3 for block number

Tags: blockchain, blocks, rpc, alchemy

Basically I'm getting an error from my RPC node provider (Alchemy) where sometimes, when I query for the block_number I get the response -3.
I don't quite understand why or if this is a rate limit related error (I'm using a free node).
Thanks!